# Backbone unit testing strategy for sync event?

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

My model sets the startAttributes after each sync:

```
    this.on('sync', function(model) {
        model.startAttributes = _.clone(model.attributes);
    });
```

How can I proceed to test if this is done correctly?

```
describe('History', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.address = new app.models.Address();
        this.sync_stub = sinon.stub(this.address, 'sync');
    });
    it("should set the startAttributes when the model syncs", function () {
        this.address.save();
        should.exist(this.startAttributes);
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        this.sync_stub.restore();
    });
});
```

I can't call save without stubbing it, because it will cause an error, but if I stub it, the sync event is never triggered. Same thing applies if I stub the sync method.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger a sync event for a model like this:

```
model.trigger('sync');
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but I don't know if it's a good thing to do, since I'm not testing if save triggers the event.